Polars custom checks being called twice in schema validation
I believe this is an issue either within python polars or potentially rust polars.
I'm using pandera with the polars backend.  While running my schema validation with cProfile, I noticed that all my custom validation checks are being called twice.  The check functions when using pandas backend are only called once.  I do not have any schema/container wide checks, just column/component checks.
Using the custom check function 'has_valid_format' as an example, for a 10 row dataframe, in pandas, I get the following:
   10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 check_functions.py:486(has_valid_format)

but with polars I get:
   20    0.000    0.000    0.040    0.002 check_functions.py:434(has_valid_format)

So using a traceback.print_stack, and some old school debug statements in the pandera and python polars source, I tracked the issue down to in expr.py, the _map_batches_wrapper.__call__ is being called twice, which I believe is coming from something in the map_batches def line self._pyexpr.map_batches call which, with some outputs, seems to be calling col("uid").map_list() (uid is our column, but not sure what map_list() is doing).  So eventually our custom check functions are being called twice on each column in the series.apply_lambda.
I verified that validation is only happening once, the expr.py def wrap_f is only being defined once (which gets the partial check func).  But then the that wrap_f eventually gets called twice.
I don't know if there is a flag I'm missing that is causing this behavior.  But every check, I get this sort of output:
Defining has_valid_format in wrap_f
Calling __call__ on <function Expr.map_elements.<locals>.wrap_f at 0x12f6f5580>
Wrap_f function has_valid_format called
Calling has_valid_format in lambda
Calling __call__ on <function Expr.map_elements.<locals>.wrap_f at 0x12f6f5580>
Wrap_f function has_valid_format called
Calling has_valid_format in lambda

But seems like isn't desired behavior.
UPDATED: Apologies, very trimmed down version of what we're doing provided below.  Running this, I get the same results.  The check is being called twice even though there is only one row of data.
import polars as pl
import pandera as pd
import re


from copy import deepcopy
from typing import Dict

from pandera.polars import Column

from typing import Any, Callable, Type

from pandera import Check
from pandera.backends.base import BaseCheckBackend
from pandera.backends.polars.checks import PolarsCheckBackend
from pandera.errors import SchemaErrors
import pandera.polars as pa

def get_template() -> Dict:
    return deepcopy(_schema_template)

def has_valid_format(value: str, regex: str) -> bool:
    return bool(re.match(regex, value))


class MyCheck(Check):
    def __init__(
        self,
        check_fn: Callable,
        id: str,
        name: str,
        description: str,
        severity: str,
        scope: str,
        **check_kwargs
    ):
        self.severity = severity
        self.scope = scope

        super().__init__(check_fn, title=id, name=name, description=description, **check_kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def get_backend(cls, check_obj: Any) -> Type[BaseCheckBackend]:
        return PolarsCheckBackend

_schema_template = {
    "uid": Column(
        str,
        title="Field 1: Unique identifier",
        checks=[MyCheck(
                    has_valid_format,
                    id="E0002",
                    name="uid.invalid_text_pattern",
                    description="Checks the format",
                    severity="Error",
                    scope="Syntax",
                    element_wise=True,
                    regex="^[A-Z0-9]+$",
                )],
    ),
    "action": Column(
        str,
        title="Action Taken",
        checks=[],
    )
}

def validate_schedule():
    data = {"uid": ["A12B"], "action": ["stop"]}
    df = pl.DataFrame(data)
    
    schema = pa.DataFrameSchema(get_template())
    try:
        import cProfile
        import pstats
        profiler = cProfile.Profile()
        profiler.enable()
        schema.validate(df, lazy=True)
        profiler.disable()
        pstats.Stats(profiler).strip_dirs().sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats("has_valid_format")
        print("Passed validation")
    except SchemaErrors as err:
        for schema_error in err.schema_errors:
            print(f"Schema Error: {schema_error}, Check: {schema_error.check}")
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    validate_schedule()

Doing this with polars results in :
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sample_issue.py:24(has_valid_format)

whereas switching it to use pandas and pandera.pandas results in:
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sample_issue.py:24(has_valid_format)


Can you provide a minimal reproducible example (an example dataframe, the user function, and the code doing the pandera validation) of the issue?

@Hericks  sample code provided.  Apologies for the oversight.

The issue appears to be with Pandera polars Checks using "element_wise=True".  When I switch the custom Checks to use groupby, or just using pa.Check(check_function, groupby="some_col"), the check function only gets called once.  Created a bug issue at https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/issues/1707
So for the time being, I would avoid element_wise = True in favor of groupby and using the lazyframe. Which according to the documentation has a warning of "Under the hood, element-wise checks use the map_elements function, which is slower than the native polars expressions API."  So probably a good idea anyway?

Awesome that you took a deep dive, narrowed down on the issue, and raised a bug report!
